# How to build a circular wall in Box2D?

Tags: collision-detection, box2d

I know that to build a wall/fence in Box2D for four sides we just need to draw an edge or a rectangle box for each side. But what if I want my sprites to move inside of a circular box? And also detect collisions on the inner side of the circular wall? If I try to make a circular body would any movable body be allowed to be inside this circular body? What is the correct way to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I only need AABB collision detection and don't care about restitution and friction. But if I have to use `b2ChainShape` in Box2D maybe what I am searching for is something that combines Box2D and simple geometric collision. Such that I can use Box2D for the AABB collisions of sprites inside the circle, but when I check the collisions between the sprites and the big circular wall I want to use simple geometric check. I just don't know if that's doable. My situation is that I put the collision detection on the server, so by using Box2D everything is measured in the world of Box2D, a.k.a "MKS" world. Now if I draw the circular wall using simple graphics, and I want to check simple geometric collisions between sprites and the wall I will have to use pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a circular wall by creating a loop using the `b2ChainShape` and passing it enough vertices to have the physics appear as round as you must have it. Note that this doesn't exactly do a circular wall; only an approximation that's really the inside of a polygon with N sides (where N is the number of vertices you provided).

Creating a wall this way will allow bodies to be within it, collide with it (like bodies would with any other static body), and be confined by it. So long as those bodies (the shape(s) of those bodies actually) are basically smaller than the boundaries of this wall at least. And yes, any movable body will be allowed inside this wall.

A circular wall could be built in other ways, but if it were me, I'd at least start with this mechanism (the `b2ChainShape`). Of the standard shapes that come with the library, it's the most memory efficient way to do this. Alternatively, one could subclass `b2Shape` and develop all the other code that'd be necessary. Or write whatever custom code was needed to simulate the physics desired. That'd be "re-inventing the wheel" so-to-speak however (unless of course the physics desired isn't already done in Box2D).

Hope this answers your questions.

Comment: Thanks. I used to do this without Box2D and I only need to detect collisions when the body moves pass the edge of the circle using simple geometric calculation. But with this `b2ChainShape` if the radius of the 'Circle' is very big the shape will consist of a plethora of vertices. Would that have negative impact of performance?

Comment: Yep. One can certainly do this without Box2D. And that might be more efficient too. What's more important at the moment though: the efficiency/performance of the code, or something like time-to-market (development time, etc)? I believe that the algorithmic performance of the `b2ChainShape` would primarily depend on how many AABBs of edges of this shape that any other body's AABBs would interact with at any given time. But that provides collision physics like restitution and friction which if you don't need may be wasted cycles.

Comment: I see. I have edited my question, please check it out. If using `b2ChainShape` may have a negative impact on performance, I also want to know if it is OK to do both Box2D AABB collision detection and simple geometric collision detection at the same time.